# what data type to use to stored these characters: '●▬ஜ۩卐۩ஜ▬●'

Tags: sql-server, special-characters, sql-server-2014, sqldatatypes, non-ascii-characters

How can I deal with ( select and print ) the following set of characters:

```
DECLARE  @V NVARCHAR(108)
SELECT @V = '●▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬ஜ۩卐۩ஜ▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬●'

SELECT @V
PRINT @V
```

even when debugging the contents of the variable is not showing properly.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed `N` before code..read here more on why we need to append N'' before characters..https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/155859/why-do-we-need-to-put-n-before-strings-in-microsoft-sql-server

```
DECLARE  @V NVARCHAR(1080)
SELECT @V = N'●▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬ஜ۩卐۩ஜ▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬●'

SELECT @V
PRINT @V
```

Comment: of course, that's right. So obvious now that you have said it!!! - tired DBA